# Google plus API - how to add "communities" as 'data-recipient'

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to include a community as a recipient by using the Plus API and the 'data-recipients' property.
When I add the community ID, it shows "unknown user".
If I click manually, that is click on the IFrame, it allows me to see and choose the community I want to share the post with.

Any help on how to do so will be much appreciated.

thank-you.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Can you file a feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this is supported. Communities are not users and the API does not support treating them as users even though in some cases they function similarly.

I tried testing this myself and I got a `name unavailable` value in the share dialog and it posted, but the share never displayed in the community.